# Where to put a custom macros file?

Tags: macros, include, automation, preamble, texmf

I have a bunch of common commands I put in document preambles. I don't always use them all, but it makes the preamble too long for my tastes.

I want to put them all in an external file (preferably in my user texmf tree). A class file seems like overkill; it isn't robust and I don't know TeX anyway. Creating a package seems intimidating as well. Can I just put the macros in a `macro.tex` in my tree and use `\include{macro.tex}` in my preamble? Also, could I include the same after `\begin{document}`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just put them all in a `mymacros.sty` file and add the single line on top (which is also optional!):

```
\ProvidesPackage{mymacros}[2011/02/23 v1.0 My own macros]
```

That's all what is required for a simple package. No plainTeX knowledge required.
Load it as usually using `\usepackage{mymacros}`

Please note that `\include` can't be used in the preamble. For this kind of files (as `.tex` *without* the above code line) you need to use `\input`.

Comment: Won't this be a problem if `mymacros.sty` includes `\usepackage` lines?

Comment: Not really. However, these should be renamed to `\RequirePackage`. (Note that `\usepackage` is `\let` to `\RequirePackage` inside `\documentclass` and defined as an error before that)

Comment: Does each package need its own `\RequirePackage` line?

Comment: Lev and Josef both have good points. I would have chosen both if I could. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: @jrhorn424: No, you *can* use `\RequirePackage` as well as `\usepackage` to load multiple packages as long you don't need to set different options for these. However, the normal way is to use one command per package. This makes it easier to remove and add packages or options and is also easier to read IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

You can of course use `\input` after `\begin{document}` but not for preamble commands. `\include` adds a new page and is meant for chapters. Simply put your commands in something like `mydef.sty` and load it with `\usepackage{mydefs}`

Comment: What makes you think you can't use `\input` for preamble commands?

Comment: @Lev: I think the point is that if `mydefs.sty` were to contain various setup the OP always finds himself writing in the preamble, it should not (and, depending on which macros were used, cannot) be loaded after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Lev You can of course `\input` preample commands, but not after `\begin{document}` jehorn242's second question´

Comment: @Josef: now I see what you are saying. Perhaps you could edit your answer to clarify that `\input` is valid both in and out of the preamble, depending on which commands you are inputting.

Comment: @Lev: So if I use `\input`, I can put it anywhere. But do all new macro definition have to happen in the preamble?

Comment: Yes, `\input` can go anywhere. Macro definitions can go anywhere. A few commands are preamble-only, the most common ones being `\documentclass` and `\usepackage`, so if you `\input` a file containing these commands, you must do so in the preamble.